# How do I request a old question to be link to my account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I asked the following question :

[How do I enable open id on a Java Webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098/how-do-i-enable-open-id-on-a-java-webapp)

I now have an account :

https://stackoverflow.com/users/438144/guillaume-cote

How should I ask the two Guillaume Coté to be the same account?

Answer (score 6):

Flag the question for moderator attention and ask them to merge the owner of the question with your registered account

Comment: Done, I'll wait for their answer.

Answer (score 4):

*Email* `team@stackexchange.com` or `team@stackoverflow.com` (there is no difference, they'll help you both places) and **include links to your profiles and the questions** you would like associated.